# How to update a file in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used `docker compose` to start a docker container. Here is a part of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  - "./list.data:/list.data:ro"
```

As you see, I mapped a file named `list.data` from the host machine to the docker container.

In the docker container, there is a process, which reads the file `/list.data` periodically. So if the file changes, the process could know about that in some time.

However, I just found that changing the file on the host machine can NOT take affect in the docker container.

So is there some method to do so but without restarting the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your YAML by a full path path reference to the host file, and remove read only flag to the docker mapped file:

```yaml
volumes:
  - "/full/path/list.data:/list.data"
```